# Is ++(a = b); faster than a = b + 1;?

Tags: c++, performance, compilation

Is it faster to use `++(a = b);` instead of `a = b + 1;`?

For my understanding, the first approach consists of the operations:

1. move the value of `b` to `a`
2. increment `a` in memory

while the second approach does:

1. push `b` and `1` to the stack
2. call add
3. pop the result to a register
4. move the register to `a`

Does it actually take less cycles? Or does the compiler (gcc for example) do an optimization so it does not make a difference?

Comment: Didn't you try to check asm generated?

Comment: Does it need to be fast? Have you profiled the application and determined that you have an issue with this code? Have you put both variants in a loop, run them 100,000 times and compared the results? *Premature optimization is the root of all evil* Knuth.

Comment: Compare the generated assembler code at different optimizations levels. You also have to consider the memory accesses and cache uses.

Comment: What is the target platform, compiler, version and compiler settings the answer should be valid under?

Comment: "Push b and 1 to the stack" - what silly architecture does that? "Call add" <- wha... wat?

Comment: You must have incredibly fast and highly optimized code if you've now reached the point of having to optimize at this level ;-)

Comment: This is micro-optimization. Let your compiler do the micro-optimizations. Focus yourself on having a readable source code and for that purpose `a = b + 1;` is much better

Comment: @Griwes One of the Unisys mainframes is a stack oriented machine.  So is the FPU on an Intel, for that matter: if this were floating point, the generated code would push `a` onto the stack, then push `b`, then add and then pop the results to where ever it was wanted.  (And on the Unisys, that's how `++` would be implemented as well: push `a` onto the stack, push `1` onto the stack, add, then pop the results into `a`.)

Comment: It's code for a physical page allocator used by a paging mechanism in a kernel... so i guess it has to be quite optimized.. :)

Comment: @m4xdev Or not.  There may be some critical parts of it which have to be very optimized, but there's probably also a lot of secondary activity which doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, ignoring the actual practical use of this, i dont really understand all the downvotes. This question was only about the theoretical performance of the two statements...

Comment: The downvotes are likely a result of the fact that this is easily testable. Theory means nothing in such matters, especially since compilers will differ in how they optimize code.

Comment: @JamesKanze, ugh, this surely qualifies as "silly architecture" (yes, so does x87 coprocessor, eh).

Comment: @Griwes Actually, it's very elegant, and it certainly makes life easier for compiler writers.

Answer (score 7):

*edit:* TIL that `++(a=b)` is <strike>wrong illegal</strike> UB, at least in pre-C++11. Nevertheless, I'll discuss this assuming it's either legal or the compiler does what you expect.

Generally speaking, `a = b + 1;` is faster.

The optimizer will most surely make the same of both. If not, it is more likely to optimize the second version, because it is a very common thing to write, and omtimizers are more likely to recognize common things than weird corner cases.

Why do I say it should be the same after optimization, but the second is faster? Because of the fellow developers. Everyone recognizes `a = b + 1;` immediately. Noone really has to think about it. The other case is more likely to trigger a reaction in the likes of "wtf is he *doing* there, and *why*?". Many people will figure out eventually *what* you did there. Some will not. Some might even introduce bugs because of it. Few people will find out *why* you did it and nevertheless stumble each time they have to read that line. ***Everyone*** will lose time wondering while reading that line. That's why the other is faster.

Caveat: all this is written silently assuming that you are talking of builtin types, like `int`s or pointers. Your interpretation of what the two do supports that. If we're talking of UDTs, the two lines are not even guaranteed to do the same. It then depends completely on how `operator=`, `operator++` and `operator+` and maybe the conversion from int are implemented. Nevertheless, if the implementations make you conside to write `++(a=b)`, they are most likely bad implementations and should be improved rather than hacked around.

**tl;dr:** if I'd catch you doing `++(a=b)` in any codebase I work on, we'd have to have a serious talk ;-)

Comment: I was beginning to wonder until I hit the last paragraph:-).  You're right to point out that development speed is usually more important than run-time speed.  Still, you should point out that not only is the alternative confusing to the reader, it isn't legal C++.

Comment: Sometimes you want a WTF bit of code just to make sure other developers have looked at the code rather than just blindly ask you dumb questions which could be easily answered by looking at the code. I once put an `index ["string"]` construct into some complex code so I could tell if other developers had tried to understand the code before asking for help, so Q's like "how does this code work" indicated they hadn't even read the code whereas "tried to understand the code but WTF is that" at least showed some effort to read the code!

Comment: @Skizz That's what trigraphs are for :-)

Comment: @JamesKanze You say `++(a = b)` is illegal and I thought the same initialy, but assignment is sequenced before value computation of (a=b), so isn't this legal in C++11?

Comment: @Skizz That's called intentional obfuscation.  It will get you fired in most companies, regardless of your intent.

Comment: @jrok C++11 has changed the rules somewhat, so I'm not sure; it's clearly illegal pre-C++11, and if I understand the _intent_ of C++11's rewriting, it was only to make it applicable to a multi-threaded environment, not to change the rules in a single threaded context.  So if it has become legal, that is an unintentional by-product of the rewrite, not an intention.  (Having said that: I'm all in favor of tightening down the rules, even more so, and eliminating undefined behavior.  Because undefined behavior means that tests are meaningless.)

Comment: @Skizz no. You don't want to make *everyone* wtf about your code, just because you have the one ignorant guy every team seems to have.

Comment: @Skizz Sorry, but that's dumb.

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks for the enlightenment. I didn't know it was UB. I think my general idea of code like that still applies :-)

Comment: It was over three years between me writing the code and someone asking about it. The code had been thoroughly tested when I wrote it and didn't need any attention until a new feature was required. It also acted as a memory trigger to remind me how the code worked and what it was supposed to do. As soon as they mentioned that piece of code I knew exactly what they were up to.

Comment: @ArneMertz Definitely.  Even if it has become legal in C++11, it's not an acceptable coding practice (except for things like IOCCC).

Comment: @Skizz if it needed a memory trigger to remind you what the code was supposed to do and how it worked, it was clearly not self-explanatory code. You should have reworked it, e.g. use meaningful names for functions and variables etc. worst case, use a comment. Every piece of code will have to be maintained *eventually*. Making maintenance harder than it needs to be is always bad practice.

Comment: @ArneMertz: you are, of course, entirely correct. I guess the devil inside wanted to have some entertainment from the WTF! moment. Would never dream of doing it now. The code was perfectly understandable if one took the time to read it properly.

Comment: @Skizz regarding that intentional correct but obfuscated code, a quote from Top Gun: "The enemy's dangerous, but right now you're worse. Dangerous and foolish."

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer to this question. The question has been flagged with C++ so we have no way of knowing what this code is actually doing without knowing the precise type of all the operands. Also, the context within which the code appears will make a difference to the way the optimiser generates code - the compiler could alias the variables and move the increment into instructions further down the program, for example, into effective address calculations for the two variables.

But the real question is, why do you care? As Arne said above, readability is far more important and you've not posted a scenario whereby any difference would have a measurable effect.

Only worry about it if it is actually causing a problem.

Answer (score 1):

With optimizations on, they generate exactly the same code for me so they will perform exactly the same. This shouldn't be a surprise as the effects of both statements are exactly the same.

<strike>`++(a = b);` is undefined behaviour because there are two unsequenced modifications to `a`.</strike>

Although the *value computation* of `a` in `a = b` is sequenced before the modification of `a` due `++`, the side-effect of `a = b` (storage to `a`) is unsequenced relative to the side-effect of `++` (again, storage to `a`).

Comment: *In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.* Doesn't this imply that the side effect of assignment to `a` is done before the result of assignment expression?

Comment: @jrok: Seems odd, I'm not sure what the difference between the "assignment" and the "value computation of the assignment expression" is supposed to be. Either way it doesn't say anything about the side-effect of the expression, storage to the assignee. Unless that is what is meant by "assignment" in that statement?

Comment: I reckon "assignment" includes the side effect. *shrug*

Comment: @jrok: Reading again, it must do otherwise that statement is redundant. Deleting again... no, wait I can just move the `<strike>` tags around.

Comment: @CharlesBailey "sequenced before" means that all side effects have occurred.  This is a distinct change from pre-C++11 (and from C11, despite the fact that the two committees worked closely together on the threading issues, with the goal of the two languages having exactly identical semantics with regards to sequencing and threading).